# Trouble handling apostrophes in php form

Tags: php, mysql

I am a graphic designer for a church website.  I don't have a great deal of programming knowledge, just enough to come here and ask.  The church is in between programmers and they have an issue a prayer request form.  When someone enters a request that contains an apostrophe, it says it's unable to submit (looking at the code, that is what it's supposed to tell them when it  can't update the db).  This is the code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('DATABASE CONNECTION GOES HERE');
    mysql_select_db('DATABASE NAME', $conn) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query="INSERT INTO prayerrequests (submitdate, submitby, submitemail, prayerrequest, posted, approved) VALUES ('$today', '$user','','”.str_replace(“’”, “’’”, $request1).”',1, 1)";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to update database");
```

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your double quotes but let's try this :

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
$query="INSERT INTO prayerrequests
(submitdate, submitby, submitemail, prayerrequest, posted, approved)
VALUES
('$today', '$user','','".mysql_real_escape_string($request1)."',1, 1)";
```